# Unable to write to parque file using fullSet.repartition(1).saveAsParquetFile("swift://notebooks.spark/tweetsFull.parquet")

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying build application using apache spark using IBM bluemix. (Ref https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-hashtags/). I am using streaming API's to stream data and have successfully created the SQL table using spark SQL. Then I have read the data using SQL select *, but when I am unable to write the data to paraque file in the object storage space on the IBM Bluxmix platform.Following is the sample code

```
.
.
.
var df = sqlContext.createDataFrame( workingRDD, schemaTweets )
df.registerTempTable("tweets_table")
df.printSchema()
  root
   |-- author: string (nullable = true)
   |-- date: string (nullable = true)
   |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
   |-- text: string (nullable = true)

val results = sqlContext.sql("select * from tweets_table limit 5")
results.show
  +--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
  |              author|                date|lang|                text|
  +--------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+
  |       abc          ?|Sun Nov 29 03:30:...|  en|RT @fdfds: W........|
  |   fdsfsdf          ?|Sun Nov 29 03:30:...|  en|#NewsIndofsdfM  R...|
  |           .fsdfdsf  |Sun Nov 29 03:30:...|  en|RT @Lsfddsfds.    ..|
  |           Wsfsfd    |Sun Nov 29 03:30:...|  en|My gfsdfsdfdshtps...|
  |           Ffsdfsdf  |Sun Nov 29 03:30:...|  en|RT @Ayfsdfsdf : W...|
  +---------------------+--------------------+----+--------------------+

  results.repartition(1).saveAsParquetFile("swift://notebooks.spark/tweets_1.parquet")
```

Here in the object storage seeing that the file tweets_1.parquet is created, But its showing as 0 bytes. Can any one let me know where I did a mistake ?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: Okay. I believe that the saveAsParquetFile is deprecated in that version and you should use `dataframe.write.parquet("..") instead. However, saveAsParquet should of course still work ;) You say that tweets_1.parquet is created, but how about the _SUCCESS file? Is that created? If not, you should probably have a look at the log files to see if any exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I tried using df.write.parquet("swift://notebooks.spark/tweetsFull_3.parquet"). But still seeing file as 0 bytes. _SUCCESS file is also 0 bytes. Using saveAsParquet() I am seeing warnings  as SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Comment: Hmm.. strange. If a _SUCCESS file is created, everything should be fine. If you do a `saveAsText` instead, is the file then also empty?

Comment: @Goutham - those errors are noted in the document as safe to ignore.  I tested this and it worked for me; no issues but I didn't note the file size.  I'll double-check.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran through this same example my Parquet file is saved in Object Storage but is broken up into several files in a subdirectory with the same name:

```
tweetsFull.parquet  12/02/2015 1:48 PM  0 KB
tweetsFull.parquet/part-r-00000-c3709e95-8f23-4ec5-bdf0-f0940b2cd94b.gz.parquet 12/02/2015 1:49 PM  16 KB
tweetsFull.parquet/_common_metadata 12/02/2015 1:49 PM  1 KB
tweetsFull.parquet/_metadata    12/02/2015 1:49 PM  3 KB
tweetsFull.parquet/_SUCCESS 12/02/2015 1:49 PM  0 KB
```

It works if I read from this file.  Is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. I was mistaken by the folder name tweets_1.parquet, which is showing as 0 bytes.I thought tweets_1.parquet is the only file which must be created. But its a folder and under that I can able to see all the files which are valid.